# Get last inserted ID return from a insert/update query

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-ce

I want to get the last inserted id returned when inserting in my visual C# program.

```
// Insert to database
try
{

    int result = int.Parse(tblClipManagerTableAdapter.InsertQuery(textBox2.Text, textBox1.Text).ToString());
    MessageBox.Show(result.ToString());
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    MessageBox.Show("Fejl: " + ex.Message.ToString());
}
```

Error is: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

I have set the tblClipManagerTableAdapter.InsertQuery execute mode to scalar.

Any help on how to return the last inserted ID with my current code and setup?

Using a local SQL database (dbClipManager.sdf).

Best regards

---

EDIT

I think I found something that I could use.

But I am very new to this. Not sure how to complety write the code?
Im used to just use the datasets, not opening connections, execute SQL cmds. :o/

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlce/thread/1d1d3267-dc29-470b-bb20-00487a39bc87/

Best regards

Answer (score 3):

There are several problems with your approach, so I'd suggest you do a quick read through of [table adapter and make sure that you've got the basics down](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tthwx(v=vs.100).aspx).

1. If you're trying to add a new record, you should be calling `TableAdapter.Insert`, not `TableAdapter.Update`
2. You can't create a second command to the database and use `@@IDENTITY` to get back the `ID` that was previously generated... this has to be returned within the same session, otherwise SQL would have no idea which ID you are expecting to receive.
3. If you set the execute mode of the table adapter to scalar, then the ID will be the return value of the method call.  [Please see this Question and Answer on the same issue that you're experiencing.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4776655/incorrect-id-is-returned-after-insert-using-tableadapter)

---

EDIT:
[Please see this walk-through for what you're trying to accomplish.](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/introduction/creating-a-data-access-layer-cs)

Comment: even in SQL Server 2000 you shouldn't use @@identity.

Comment: @HLGEM You're right... thanks.  For some reason I thought `SCOPE_IDENITY()` was added in 2005, but it was added in 2000.  I guess I spent more time in 7.0 than I care to remember.

Comment: @MichaelFredrickson thank you very much for your fast answer.
Sorry for the UPDATE / INSERT mismatch. I have editted my question.

I have now set the execute mode of the tableadapter (tblClipManagerTableAdapter.InsertQuery) to scalar.

Still the same error appears in my try / catch.

Where to put the SCOPE_IDENTITY() ?

Comment: @user1281991  You would add the `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()` at the end of the insert statement that is typically auto-generated for your table adapter.  [This article will walk you through this step-by-step](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/introduction/creating-a-data-access-layer-cs).

Comment: @MichaelFredrickson sorry but it still doens't work. Visual Studio won't allow me to put the SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() in a insert query.

Seems that SQLCE doens't support that?

Comment: @user1281991 I'm sorry, I didn't realize you were using SQLCE; in that case, you may have to use `@@IDENTITY` afterall...