# c# last insert id using table adapter

Tags: c#, insert, identity

I'm trying to get the last inserted id out of the database. I've tried many different code snippets but still having no luck. Here's the code I'm using for the inserts. I need the last insert id from the first to insert as nId in the second. I've tried SELECT @@IDENTITY but null value errors appeared which I couldn't locate. Can anybody show me the correct code please?

```
// Insert new user
daUsers.Insert(textBoxUsername.Text, textBoxPassword.Text);

// Insert new Twitter OAuth
daTwitterOAuth.Insert(nId, textBoxConsumerKey.Text, textBoxConsumerSecret.Text, textBoxToken.Text, textBoxTokenSecret.Text);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to add a new record, you should be calling TableAdapter.Insert, not TableAdapter.Update
You can't create a second command to the database and use @@IDENTITY to get back the ID that was previously generated... this has to be returned within the same session, otherwise SQL would have no idea which ID you are expecting to receive.
If you set the execute mode of the table adapter to scalar, then the ID will be the return value of the method call. Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4776655/incorrect-id-is-returned-after-insert-using-tableadapter) [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9876106/get-last-inserted-id-return-from-a-insert-update-query) and Answer on the same issue that you're experiencing.

Comment: Been there already! In the code above I'm using an insert method, changed the execute mode to scalar and this is my sql:


    INSERT INTO [dbTblUsers]([strUsername], [strPassword])
    VALUES (@p1,@p2);
    SELECT @@IDENTITY;


How do I cast @@identity into an int? Like this?

    nId = (int)daUsers.InsertQuery(textBoxUsername.Text, textBoxPassword.Text);

Answer (score 0):

Someone has mentioned `@@Identity` which is fine, but what if somebody else performs an insert elsewhere before you reach that line in `SQL`?

I'd do this.

```
Create Procedure [Proc]

@Id as int output = 0

as

Insert into Table
Select * from AnotherTable

SET @Id = (SELECT Scope_Identity)
```

Then in `.NET` add your output parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Been there already! In the code above I'm using an insert method, changed the execute mode to scalar and this is my sql:

```
INSERT INTO [dbTblUsers]([strUsername], [strPassword])
VALUES (@p1,@p2);
SELECT @@IDENTITY;
```

How do I cast @@identity into an int? Like this?

```
nId = (int)daUsers.InsertQuery(textBoxUsername.Text, textBoxPassword.Text);
```